# How to use turn.js in Ionic 2?

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic2, angular2-directives, turnjs

i have a Ionic v1 project using turn.js but now i'm using Ionic v2.
I'm having problem with import the turn.js using with the jQuery.

```
angular.module('albumController', [])

.directive('flipbook', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        element.turn({
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px',
            pages: 8
        }).turn('peel', 'br');

        element.addClass('flipbook');
        return function (scope, el) {
            el.on('click', '[data-page]', function (e) {
                el.turn('page', $(e.target).data('page'));
            }); 
        };
    },
    templateUrl: "flipbook.html"
}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having. A better explanation would help people find an answer for you.

Comment: @Fencer04 I can't use the method "turn" in $('#flipbook').turn('next'); The vs code says that Property 'turn' does not exist on typeof jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have the answer. For me I do the following:

1. install jquery for ionic(check it [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/jquery-in-ionic-2-and-typescript/54015/2))
2. `npm install --save turn.js`
3. `import $ from "jquery"; 
   import "turn.js";`

just that you can use $().turn();

hope it help :D